# Django duplicate database queries

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-debug-toolbar

I am using `django_debug_toolbar` for analyzing performance of web page. What confuses me in the results is the database queries. No matter I did everything as it should be (I suppose), results tab still shows duplicate database queries warning. For illustrating this problem, I set out django project as simple as below:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question, Choice


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {'questions': Question.objects.all()})
```

**index.html**

```
{% for question in questions %}
  <p>{{ question.question_text }}</p>
  <ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
      <li>{{ choice.votes }} votes - {{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

In the above html file and view, I load all questions and their related choices. For testing, I added only 2 question and 2 and 4 choices for them respectively (6 choices in total). And `django_debug_toolbar` SQL result are as below:

[image]

[image]

What should I do for avoiding these duplicate SQL queries? I think that these duplicated query may have serious impacts on performance for big websites. What is your approach and best practices to avoid these issues in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) the related `Choice`s. Then Django will make an extra query to fetch the `Choice`s all at once, and do the JOIN at the Python/Django level.

```
def index(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'polls/index.html',
        {'questions': Question.objects.prefetch_related('choice_set')}
    )
```